# Make staus bar visible without overlapping view

Tags: iphone

I have a tab bar with two views.  In the first view the iPhone status bar is hidden using `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES animated:YES]`.  When the second view is loaded, and the status bar is made visible again using `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:NO animated:YES]` it overlaps the view.  How do I make the status bar visible again without overlapping the second view?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Try this code.
The dot is a dash..

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
  // to fix the controller showing under the status bar
  self.view.frame = [[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame];
  }